# How to check for Nan values in column headers in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I want to add a check if the column headers have NaN or unnamed to raise an exception.
`def column_check(x): if 'unnamed' in x.lower(): return False`
I have added for unnamed this way which returns false if no headers are present in specified header column. I am looking for a similar logic to check for any NAs/ NanNs in the header of df.
I would need to rise an exception if the df header contains unnamed,NAs or NANs

Comment: Try using: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html

Comment: No I want a function to check if there is no Nan,null,numeric or unnamed in first row of excel or csv while reading as `df` else raise exception